# JPA- additional column for multi-developer

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

If two developers work with the same database and one person adds an additional column in entity A and the table (TA) related with A has changed and the other developer develops with the old entity A, will the table be fine or will errors occur?

I want to know if I can ignore additional columns in a multi-developer case when the additional column can be null or have a default value.

Comment: Yes, JPA and queries it generates won't use 'select * from..', so won't care about extra fields added to tables. Care has to be taken though as table/schema changes that aren't additive are huge problems, as one version selecting a field that is no longer there is an exception, and data itself (think enums) stored that cannot be read in by one version are exceptions the application usually cannot overcome.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Strictly speaking, you're not using JPA, which is only a specification, but probably hibernate.

Hibernate can automatically migrate databases if configured so. There are two configuration parameters responsible for that ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)):

- `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` which is a boolean value and decides if automatic migration (DDL) is used at all
- `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` which is an enum value and decides in which way the automatic migration is performed.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` has 4 allowed values (`none,` `validate`, `update`, `create-drop`) with `none` being the default value. The automatic migration is carried **at the startup of the spring boot application**.

So it highly depends on:

- ddl being activated at all
- the mode of auto generation
- when which developer starts the spring boot application

As you can see, this is not quite optimal, because it leads to inconsistencies and unexpected behavior. You should consider giving each developer his or her own database for development purposes or at least disable ddl on a shared database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Give each developer his or her own database for development purposes is a good way, but it also bring us more work to make each database has the same data for each developer when they started to develop and for better testing. for my allpication setting: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update, spring.jpa.generate-ddl is not setted. the developer which not modify the entity start first.  for this case, when the modify-developer starts his service, the table will be changed, and will the not-modified-developer's service occurs error when save or query?